# Will I reduce the life of my SSD prematurely?

Tags: 12.04, installation, vmware, ssd

I purchased my first ssd drive and since I have been learning linux figured I would ask about installing ubuntu 12.04 LTS on a ssd. I know from doing research there was issues with write life on a ssd. With the Samsung EVO 840 series 250gig is there any reason to worry about the write life? I would also like to install vms as I study security, so I would install kali linux and some windows OS. I would just like some advice if possible for I do not want to kill my SSD in like a year

Comment: Your question is a bit to broad and [parts of it have already been answered](http://askubuntu.com/search?tab=votes&q=ssd). For questions and recommendations on hardware and especially what issues other people experience, the Ubuntu forums might be better suited. You may want to read up on current technology used in consumer SSDs starting with Wikipedia and how that correlates with different degradation characteristics.

Answer (score 1):

Enable TRIM

TRIM (Trim command let an OS know which SSD blocks are not being used and can be cleared)

Back up fstab first in case something wrong happen.

```
# cp /etc/fstab ~/fstab.bk

enter code here
```

Edit fstab file

```
# nano /etc/fstab
```

Add discard to your ssd drives or partitions, after ext4

```
UUID=bef10b86-494d-41c6-aa46-af72cfba90fd / ext4 discard,errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

Add noatime,nodiratime to your ssd drives or partitions, after ext4

```
UUID=bef10b86-494d-41c6-aa46-af72cfba90fd / ext4 discard,noatime,nodiratime,errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

To keep your ssd live longer, you should tweak and optimize SSD for Ubuntu, you can read the complete article from nam huy linux blog at http://namhuy.net/1563/how-to-tweak-and-optimize-ssd-for-ubuntu-linux-mint.html

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you'll find usefull this tutorial:

## Installing Ubuntu on SSD

PART 1
http://labnotes.decampo.org/2012/12/installing-ubuntu-1210-on-ssd-part-1.html

PART 2
http://labnotes.decampo.org/2012/12/installing-ubuntu-1210-on-ssd-part-2.html

PART 3
http://labnotes.decampo.org/2012/12/installing-ubuntu-1210-on-ssd-part-3.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.